# How to set depth of GNU chess in winboard?

Tags: engines, depth, winboard

I have downloaded GNU chess 5.07 in windows 10. I am running it in winboard  4.8.0. When I start GNU chess in winboard, it plays with full strength. However, I want to set particular depth and want GNU to play at that level. How can I do that? I read help sections of Winboard and GNU chess. They have given command to set depth. However, I don't know how and where to write those commands? For example, Where should I write "depth 2"? How to give that command?

Other pre-installed engines (Fairy max, fruits) are too strong for me. When I click "engine 1 settings" in winboard options, no option to set depth appears.

Answer (score 1):

To set a depth, you can use the "force" command. Here is how:

1. Click "Engine 1 Settings" and then "Edit" to open the command prompt. Then, type "new" to start a new game.
2. Type "force" to put it in "force" mode. This let's you make moves for the engine.
3. Make the first few moves for all sides. This should be done by typing the moves into the command prompt. For example, you may type e3 and then it will move the pawn to e3.
4. After you have made the opening moves, you should type "go depth X" to it search for X moves ahead.
5. Finally, you should type "move" to make it play its move on your desired depth.

Repeat 4 and 5 until the end of the game. It will not make any moves automatically. You will have to use the move command every time.

Comment: But when I click "first engine settings", only. Two option appears: OK and CANCEL. And pop  up box is blank. I can't press edit until I click "ok" or "cancel"? Have you tried it?

Comment: I don't have the same version as you, could that be it @ramanujan

Comment: which versions do you have? I'll install that.